# How to scrape all the movie reviews from IMDB using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm new to web scraping and hoping to use it for sentimental analysis. I've successfully scrapped the first 10 reviews. For 280 other reviews, I was hesitated to repeat the following process for over 20 times... I was wondering if there's a package/function that allow me to scrape all the reviews in an easier way? Thanks so much!

```
library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(plyr)
HouseofCards_IMDb <- read_html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1856010/reviews?ref_=tt_urv")

#Used SelectorGadget as the CSS Selector
reviews <- HouseofCards_IMDb %>% html_nodes("#pagecontent") %>%
html_nodes("div+p") %>%
html_text()

#perfrom data cleaning on user reviews
reviews <- gsub("\r?\n|\r", " ", reviews) 
reviews <- tolower(gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", " ", reviews))
sapply(reviews, function(x){})
print(reviews)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

If you go to the second page of reviews, you will notice how the URL changes from `http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1856010/reviews` to `http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1856010/reviews?start=10`.

For the last page: `http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1856010/reviews?start=290`.

All you have to do is to loop over the pages:

```
result <- c()
for(i in c(1, seq(10, 290, 10))) {
  link <- paste0("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1856010/reviews?start=",i)
  HouseofCards_IMDb <- read_html(link)

  # Used SelectorGadget as the CSS Selector
  reviews <- HouseofCards_IMDb %>% html_nodes("#pagecontent") %>%
    html_nodes("div+p") %>%
    html_text()

  # perfrom data cleaning on user reviews
  reviews <- gsub("\r?\n|\r", " ", reviews) 
  reviews <- tolower(gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", " ", reviews))
  sapply(reviews, function(x){})
  result <- c(result, reviews)
}
```

Notice, that we start with `http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1856010/reviews?start=1`which is similar to `http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1856010/reviews`.

Comment: Unfortunately this has been since disabled with that new ajax crap :/

Comment: I've just posted an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71271735/scarping-all-the-reviews-of-a-imdb-movie-in-r/71271943#71271943 which deals with the new ajax issue